# .Net Immutable Collections with WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, system.reactive, immutability

Has anybody found a nice pattern for binding **[ImmutableCollections](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable)** ( from the MS BCL ) to a **WPF DataGrid**? To represent mutablility of an immutable structure I would wrap it with **ISubject** to track changes and provide new versions to the datagrid.

```
ISubject<ImmutableList<T>> <--(binding)--> DataGrid
```

The DataGrid obviously needs a mutable collection such as **ObservableCollection** directly under it so perhaps the problem can be reduced to

```
ISubject<ImmutableList<T>> <-----> ObservableCollection<T>
```

Any suggestions?

[ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)

Comment: I'm just curious, but why would you want to do that? We can do that now... we just need an extra collection (which is what you'll get inside your immutable collection anyway).

Comment: My application model is based on immutable collections which allows easy undo / redo behaviour. Instead of tracking change deltas I will just keep a stack of the latest states. Not sure what you mean by getting an extra collection ``inside your immutable collection``. I'm talking about the collections library defined here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable whose implementation is opaque and probably quite complex.

Comment: Interesting. I just meant that internally, immutable collections provide this functionality by using additional private collections.

Comment: Well the data structure that an ImmutableList uses internally won't look like any mutable list you have ever seen before. It will be some crazy optimized linked list thing that will be no easier to bind to a DataGrid than anything else. But you were saying you have a good idea on how to build a wrapper collection to the above nicely?

Comment: Sorry, no... I was just curious.

Comment: You did say "We can do that now" Had my hopes up ;)

Comment: I don't think it will be easy to do because you would need to take versions of the immutable and diff them to produce the action required to update the mutable mirror version.

Comment: Oh that... my custom framework has data type classes that each hold an instance of their own type. This enables me to know which properties have changed and undo the changes. If you had a collection of that type, then you could have multiple levels of undo/redo. There is also the normal way of implementing undo/redo by storing all executed `Command` objects and parameters. Good luck with your interesting project.

Comment: Ok I had a hack at it in my own answer. See below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace ReactiveUI.Ext
{
    public class ImmutableListToReactive<T> : ReactiveObject, ICollection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, IDisposable, IList<T>
    where T : class, Immutable
    {
        private  ISubject<ImmutableList<T>> _Source;

        ImmutableList<T> _Current;
        public ImmutableList<T> Current
        {
            get { return _Current; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Current, value); }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _Subscription.Dispose();
        }


        public ImmutableListToReactive( ISubject<ImmutableList<T>> source )
        {
            _Source = source;
            _Subscription = source.Subscribe(newVersion =>
            {
                if ( !rebound )
                {
                    _Current = newVersion;
                    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
                }
            });
        }

        private void OnNext( ImmutableList<T> list )
        {
            rebound = true;
            _Current = list;
            try
            {
                _Source.OnNext(list);
            }
            finally
            {
                rebound = false;
            }
        }

        public void Add( T item )
        {
            OnNext(_Current.Add(item));
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, new List<T>(){item}, Current.Count - 1));
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            OnNext(_Current.Clear());
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }

        public bool Contains( T item )
        {
            return _Current.Contains(item);
        }

        public void CopyTo( T[] array, int arrayIndex )
        {
            _Current.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return _Current.Count; }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool Remove( T item )
        {
            var idx = _Current.IndexOf(item);
            var next = _Current.Remove(item);
            if ( next == _Current )
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                OnNext(next);
                OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item, idx));
                return true;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _Current.GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _Current.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        private  IDisposable _Subscription;


        bool rebound = false;
        protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged( NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e )
        {
            if ( !rebound )
            {
                rebound = true;
                if ( CollectionChanged != null )
                {
                    CollectionChanged(this, e);
                }
                rebound = false;
            }
        }

        public int IndexOf( T item )
        {
            return _Current.IndexOf(item);
        }

        public void Insert( int index, T item )
        {
            OnNext(_Current.Insert(index, item));
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index));
        }

        public void RemoveAt( int index )
        {
            var itemToBeRemoved = _Current[index];
            OnNext(_Current.RemoveAt(index));
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, itemToBeRemoved, index));
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return _Current[index];
            }
            set
            {
                OnNext(_Current.SetItem(index, value));
                OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, value, index));
                OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, value, index));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a test case

```
using FluentAssertions;
using ReactiveUI.Subjects;
using System;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using Xunit;

namespace ReactiveUI.Ext.Spec
{
    public class Data : Immutable
    {
        public int A { get; private set; }
        public int B { get; private set; }

        public  bool Equals(Data other){
            return A == other.A && B == other.B;
        }
        public  bool Equals(object o){
            Data other = o as Data;
            if ( other == null )
            {
                return false;
            }
            return this.Equals(other);
        }

        public static bool operator ==( Data a, Data b )
        {
            return a.Equals(b);
        }
        public static bool operator !=( Data a, Data b )
        {
            return !a.Equals(b);
        }

        public Data( int a, int b )
        {
            A = a;
            B = b;
        }
    }

    public class DataMutable : ReactiveObject, IDisposable
    {
        int _A;
        public int A
        {
            get { return _A; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _A, value); }
        }
        int _B;
        public int B
        {
            get { return _B; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _B, value); }
        }

        IDisposable _Subscriptions;
        public DataMutable( ILens<Data> dataLens )
        {
            _Subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable();
            var d0 = dataLens.Focus(p => p.A).TwoWayBindTo(this, p => p.A);
            var d1 = dataLens.Focus(p => p.B).TwoWayBindTo(this, p => p.B);
            _Subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable(d0, d1);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _Subscriptions.Dispose();
        }
    }


    public class ImmutableListToReactiveSpec : ReactiveObject
    {
        ImmutableList<Data> _Fixture;
        public ImmutableList<Data> Fixture
        {
            get { return _Fixture; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Fixture, value); }
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ReactiveListSux()
        {
            var a = new ReactiveList<int>();
            var b = a.CreateDerivedCollection(x => x);

            a.Add(10);
            b.Count.Should().Be(1);

        }


        [Fact]
        public void ShouldWork()
        {
            Fixture = ImmutableList<Data>.Empty;

            // Convert an INPC property to a subject
            ISubject<ImmutableList<Data>> s = this.PropertySubject(p => p.Fixture);

            var MutableList = new ImmutableListToReactive<Data>(s);

            var DerivedList = MutableList.CreateDerivedCollection(x => x);

            Fixture = Fixture.Add(new Data(10, 20));
            DerivedList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);

            Fixture = Fixture.Add(new Data(11, 21));
            DerivedList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);

            Fixture = Fixture.Add(new Data(12, 22));
            MutableList.Count.Should().Be(3);
            DerivedList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);
            MutableList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);

            MutableList.Add(new Data(33, 88));
            MutableList.Count.Should().Be(4);
            DerivedList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);
            MutableList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);

            MutableList[1] = new Data(99, 21);
            MutableList.Count.Should().Be(4);
            DerivedList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);
            MutableList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);

            var itemAtOne = MutableList[1];
            MutableList.RemoveAt(1);
            MutableList.Should().NotContain(itemAtOne);
            MutableList.Count.Should().Be(3);
            DerivedList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);
            MutableList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);

            var i = new Data(78, 32);
            MutableList.Insert(0, i);
            DerivedList[0].Should().Be(i);
            MutableList.Count.Should().Be(4);
            DerivedList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);
            MutableList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);

            var j = new Data(18, 22);
            MutableList.Insert(3, j);
            DerivedList[3].Should().Be(j);
            MutableList.Count.Should().Be(5);
            DerivedList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);
            MutableList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);

            var k = new Data(18, 22);
            MutableList.Add(k);
            DerivedList[DerivedList.Count-1].Should().Be(k);
            MutableList.Count.Should().Be(6);
            DerivedList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);
            MutableList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);

            MutableList.Remove(i);
            DerivedList[DerivedList.Count-1].Should().Be(k);
            MutableList.Count.Should().Be(5);
            DerivedList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);
            MutableList.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(Fixture);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ReactiveObject` class? Is it a part of some framework?

Comment: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/main/src/ReactiveUI/ReactiveObject/ReactiveObject.cs